# Python/Pytorch - how to use Image arrays?

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to put image data in a neural network, but I am having trouble using the Image datatype.
I read my data here using Pytorch;

```
import torch
import torchvision
import numpy as np
from settings import Settings

class Data_Read:
    @staticmethod
    def getTrain():
        train_dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(
            root=Settings.pathTrainImagesCopy,
            transform=torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()
        )
        train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
            train_dataset,
            batch_size=64,
            num_workers=0,
            shuffle=True
        )
        return train_loader

    @staticmethod
    def getTest():
        test_dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(
            root=Settings.pathTestImagesCopy,
            transform=torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()
        )
        test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
            test_dataset,
            batch_size=64,
            num_workers=0,
            shuffle=True
        )
        return test_loader
```

The following code creates a single dimension column of images;

```
class Imagez:
    @staticmethod
    def Get(arr):
        imageData = []
        for item in arr:
            filePath = item
            img = Image.open(filePath).convert('LA')
            imageData.append(img)

        return imageData
```

And these methods are called from the main class as follows;

```
trainData = Data_Read.getTrain()
testData = Data_Read.getTest()

arrTrain = np.array(trainData.dataset.imgs)[:,0]
labelTrain = trainData.dataset.targets

arrTest = np.array(testData.dataset.imgs)[:,0]
labelTest = testData.dataset.targets

X_Train = Imagez.Get(arrTest)
```

I find whenever I try to use the Images datatype I in X_Train I get into trouble with error messages. 
For example;

```
mlp = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(10,10,10), max_iter=1000 )
mlp.fit(X_Train, labelTrain)
```

Will give me this error message;

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "c:\Users\hijik.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.11.50794\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py",
>   line 43, in 
>       main(ptvsdArgs)   File "c:\Users\hijik.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.11.50794\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd__main__.py",
>   line 432, in main
>       run()   File "c:\Users\hijik.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.11.50794\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd__main__.py",
>   line 316, in run_file
>       runpy.run_path(target, run_name='**main**')   File "C:\Users\hijik\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line
>   263, in run_path
>       pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)   File "C:\Users\hijik\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line
>   96, in _run_module_code
>       mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)   File "C:\Users\hijik\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line
>   85, in _run_code
>       exec(code, run_globals)   File "d:\702\702-Coursework-Task-5\src\Main.py", line 74, in 
>       mlp.fit(X_Train, Y_TrainLabels)   File "C:\Users\hijik\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\multilayer_perceptron.py",
>   line 981, in fit
>       return self._fit(X, y, incremental=(self.warm_start and   File "C:\Users\hijik\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\multilayer_perceptron.py",
>   line 323, in _fit 
>       X, y = self._validate_input(X, y, incremental)   File "C:\Users\hijik\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\multilayer_perceptron.py",
>   line 919, in _validate_input
>       multi_output=True)   File "C:\Users\hijik\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py",
>   line 719, in check_X_y
>       estimator=estimator)   File "C:\Users\hijik\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py",
>   line 496, in check_array
>       array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, order=order)   File "C:\Users\hijik\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py",
>   line 538, in asarray
>       return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order) TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not
>   'Image'

I am thinking I need to convert my images to another data type. What advice would you give?

EDIT - this is the minimum reproducible error;

```
X_Train = []
filePath = '..\\images\\Train\\anger\\S010_004_00000014.png'
img = Image.open(filePath).convert('LA')
X_Train.append(img)
Y_TrainLabels = ["0"]
mlp = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(10,10,10), max_iter=1000 )
mlp.fit(X_Train, Y_TrainLabels)
```

Comment: Can you share the full error traceback? What do you understand from that error message? Have you isolated it, do you have a [mcve]?

Comment: Full error traceback plus simplified code, than you for getting back @AMC

Comment: Not directly related to the issue (I think), but is that all the code in the ImageZ and Data_Read classes?

Comment: Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: Alright, I believe I know what caused the error. I think this is an issue of design or logic, not just a programming bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your `Imagez` class returns list of `PIL` images, those cannot be used for training as you need number representations.

Easy fix would be:

```
import torchvision


class Imagez:
    @staticmethod
    def Get(arr):
        imageData = []
        for item in arr:
            filePath = item
            # This transforms below
            img = torchvision.transforms.functional.to_tensor(
                Image.open(filePath).convert("LA")
            )
            imageData.append(img)

        return imageData
```

See [`convert`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert) docs and whether you really need it.

Secondly, if you are going for `sklearn` and it's `MLPClassifier`, you have transform those arrays into `np.array`.

For each you can call `.numpy()` on pytorch tensor to convert it and stack it afterwards into an array.

Furthermore, your inputs and outputs seem to be images, you either have to `flatten` those into a single vector for fully connected layers or use convolutional neural networks and PyTorch, for example the network below:

```
import torch

model = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=3),
    torch.nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=3),
    torch.nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=3),
    torch.nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=3),
    torch.nn.Conv2d(128, 1, kernel_size=3),
)
```

You could find some basic tutorials on PyTorch website, [60 Minute Blitz](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/deep_learning_60min_blitz.html) seems like a good starting point for you cause there is a lot to fix here.